# Why isn't my new index/table being created on the filegroup I specify?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filegroups

Results from @@Version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5500.0 (X64) 
Sep 21 2011 22:45:45 
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

Here is the database definition

```
CREATE DATABASE [Scratch] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'Scratch_mdf', FILENAME = N'N:\MSSQL\TEST\Primary\Scratch_mdf.mdf' , SIZE = 17664KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%), 
 FILEGROUP [DATA]  DEFAULT 
( NAME = N'Scratch_dat1a', FILENAME = N'N:\MSSQL\TEST\Data\Scratch_dat1a.ndf' , SIZE = 14539584KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%), 
( NAME = N'Scratch_dat1b', FILENAME = N'N:\MSSQL\TEST\Data\Scratch_dat1b.ndf' , SIZE = 12016128KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%), 
 FILEGROUP [INDEX] 
( NAME = N'Scratch_idx1', FILENAME = N'N:\MSSQL\TEST\Index\Scratch_idx1.ndf' , SIZE = 92864KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%), 
( NAME = N'Scratch_idx2', FILENAME = N'N:\MSSQL\TEST\Index\Scratch_idx2.ndf' , SIZE = 84416KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%), 
( NAME = N'Scratch_idx3', FILENAME = N'N:\MSSQL\TEST\Index\Scratch_idx3.ndf' , SIZE = 84416KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%), 
( NAME = N'Scratch_idx4', FILENAME = N'N:\MSSQL\TEST\Index\Scratch_idx4.ndf' , SIZE = 92864KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%), 
 FILEGROUP [PM_G0] 
( NAME = N'PM_data0', FILENAME = N'N:\MSSQL\PDB1\Data\PM_data0.ndf' , SIZE = 768000KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'Scratch_log1', FILENAME = N'N:\MSSQL\TEST\Log\Scratch_log1.ldf' , SIZE = 833024KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%) 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [Scratch] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
```

Here is the code to create the table and to add a clustered index.  In both cases I'm specifying filegroup PM_G0 but when I check its on filegroup DATA.

```
CREATE TABLE Scratch.dbo.STUPID_TEST (dummycol int) ON [PM_G0];
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_test ON stupid_test(dummycol) ON PM_G0; 
-- Tried the filegroup name with/without brackets just in case
```

I'm checking the location of the first heap, then clustered index by using this query:

```
SELECT o.name objectname, fg.name filegroupname, sdf.name as datafile,i.name indexname, partition_id, partition_number, [rows]
FROM sys.partitions p
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id=p.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON o.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id=p.object_id and p.index_id=i.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON fg.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_files sdf ON sdf.data_space_id=fg.data_space_id
WHERE o.name = 'STUPID_TEST'
```

Interesting test.  I changed the default filegroup to [index].  Confirmed that [index] was in fact the default index in sys.filegroups then dropped and re-created my clustered index and it still went to the [DATA] filegroup.  Code below

```
ALTER DATABASE Scratch MODIFY FILEGROUP [index] DEFAULT;
GO
DROP INDEX dbo.STUPID_TEST.IX_test;
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_test ON stupid_test(dummycol) ON [PM_G0];
GO
```

Comment: Is Scratch.mdf smaller than 17664??  PM_GO will not be used unless DATA is Full as DATA is set to default.

Comment: I should be able to force a table/index to be on a different FG shouldn't I?

Comment: Wrong! There is nothing wrong with the way he is creating the clustered index. It should use the filegroup he mentioned. Your sample code works as expected on my machine.

Comment: Which begs the question why is it not working on mine.  I generated the DB code directly from the DB I'm using and copied the other code directly also.  Only thing I changed was the directory the files are going to and got rid of some of the extra files in one of the filegroups (there were about a dozen which seemed like a bit much)

Comment: I can't reproduce either - I used the same code (changing only the paths) and the heap and CI both end up on the right FG. What is the exact @@VERSION? I noticed that you used a database prefix on the create table, which makes it possible you're not in the right database for part or all of the test - could you be in the context of another database which also has a table called STUPID_TEST (perhaps model or tempdb)?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm in the right database.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE Scratch
  MODIFY FILEGROUP PM_GO DEFAULT;
GO`

Comment: @ECarterYoung so set that to be the default filegroup, and then set it back? (Presumably, he doesn't want *all* objects on that filegroup, just *this* one.) In any case, the statement he's using should put the data on the right filegroup (as it does on my system), and shouldn't require changing filegroup properties.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, That's not why I'm having him test it.  If the Alter fails, then he has a user problem, which explains why it works on yours and not his...

Comment: @ECarterYoung Great, you should put more context like that in your original comments, instead of having to get it coaxed and pulled from you, because without context that looks like you're just blindly whipping out what you think the solution might be... anyway, I'd be really surprised if he can create a database, and create filegroups, and create files, and create tables and indexes on filegroups, but have that fail silently. A permissions issue should yield an error, not silent creation on the wrong FG.

Comment: @ECarterYoung I'm having the same problem as my user and I'm a sysadmin so it shouldn't be a user problem.  I am going to try changing the default back and forth to see if it fixes things.

Comment: Does Scratch have a Primary Key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thanks to everyone who tried to help me with this here and on twitter.  We did however finally find the answer.  It turns out that someone created a database trigger on model.  The trigger parses every create index/table command and changes it to a DATA filegroup if it's a heap or clustered index and an INDEX filegroup for everything else.  We were then able to track the trigger back to a policy.